# Empty Row in Firebase UI with Condition?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a problem with Firebase when using FirebaseUI. It adds an unwanted empty row when the condition is not `true`.

I need to delete this Empty Row.

this is the image Show the problem :

[image]

```
 DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("*****");
     FirebaseListAdapter<Opinions> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Opinions>(this,Opinions.class,android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,databaseReference) {
         @Override
         protected void populateView(View v, Opinions model, int position) {
             TextView textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
             TextView textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

             Typeface Myfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/gernralfont.ttf");

             textView1.setTypeface(Myfont);
             textView2.setTypeface(Myfont);
             textView2.setTextSize(17);
             textView2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#6eaafc"));
             textView1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4d70a0"));

             if (model.isApproval() == true)
             {
                 textView1.setText( "\n" + model.getStu_name() + " / " + model.getStu_feild() + "\n" );
                 textView2.setText(model.getStu_comment() + "\n");
             }



         }
     };

    hilist.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

How I can remove this empty line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app is current reading *all* data at the location. But since you're only interested in showing data that is approved, you should only read those child nodes.

You can do this with a [Firebase Database query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), which you can then pass into the adapter instead of the current reference:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("*****");
Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("approval").equalTo(true);
FirebaseListAdapter<Opinions> firebaseListAdapter = 
  new FirebaseListAdapter<Opinions>(this, Opinions.class,
                                    android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, query) {
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks Frank , I have modified my code depending on what I pointed out to him .. but my application does not working ? where is the problem please ?

Comment: now my code is working .. but give me all the data in the nodes .. Even that has not been adopted